# I don't get correct information from GRUB multiboot2 | OS Development

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, bootloader, grub

I'm currently trying out grub by writing my own OS. The whole thing with the help of the docs and open source code. Since I'm having a bit of a hard time with the resources I find, I can't really make any progress. Although I am now able to understand how the multiboot header is structured and was able to activate the frame buffer (I think), in any case the QEMU window has enlarged and the cursor has disappeared. Now I tried, as I read online, to check after the boot and kernel call whether all the information is correct but somehow it doesn't... can you please take a look at it? I just have a black screen.

Thanks

I just 1:1 directly importet the multiboot2.h header from the grub github.

Serial debug:
Hello, World!
No framebuffer info provided by bootloader
Flags: 0
1000

header.asm:

```
section .multiboot_header
    align 8                  ; The header must be 64-bit aligned

    ; Multiboot header magic number
    dd 0xE85250D6             ; magic
    dd 0                      ; architecture (0 for 32-bit)
    dd header_end - header_start ; header_length
    dd -(0xE85250D6 + 0 + (header_end - header_start)) ; checksum

align 8
header_start:
align 8
header_framebuffer_tag:
    dw 5                                    ; framebuffer settings
    dw 1
    dd header_framebuffer_tag_end - header_framebuffer_tag
    dd 0
    dd 0
    dd 32
header_framebuffer_tag_end:
align 8
end_tag:
    ; End tag
    dw 0                      ; type = 0 (end tag)
    dw 0
    dd 8                      ; size
align 8
header_end:



global start
section .text
global kentry
extern kernel_main
bits 32
kentry: 
  call kernel_main
```

entry.c:

```c
#include "multiboot2.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include "driver/serial.h"

void kernel_main(uint32_t magic, multiboot_info_t *info) {
    init_serial();
    write_string_serial("Hello, World!\n");
    
    if (!(info->flags & MULTIBOOT_INFO_FRAMEBUFFER_INFO)) {
        write_string_serial("No framebuffer info provided by bootloader\nFlags: ");
        write_number_serial(info->flags, 16); // Hexadecimal
        write_string_serial("\n");
        write_number_serial(MULTIBOOT_INFO_FRAMEBUFFER_INFO, 16); // Hexadecimal
        write_string_serial("\n");
        return;
    }
}
```

grub config:

```
set TIMEOUT=0
set default=0
set gfxmode=auto
insmod vbe
insmod all_video

menuentry "V-OS 0.1" {
  multiboot2 /boot/kernel.bin
  boot
}
```